# Thread limited number of SQL database restores

Tags: powershell

Trying find an example or a starting point for a project I have to restore databases into a test environment.   I have a list of 40+  sql instances, databases, and backup location and like to use the cmdlet Restore-SQLDatabases but only allow 3 restores to occur at a time.  To minimize the impact on our network/storage I don't want to initiate all 40+ restores at one time.  The list of what needs to be restored are contained in a csv and when testing can get the restores to go but not sure what options I'd have to only thread only 3 at a time.

Comment: I'd probably use one of the [`RunspaceFactory` examples](http://www.get-blog.com/?p=189) out there to queue up a bunch of jobs and limit the threads to 3.

Comment: I found that link too and have tried using that with limited success.  I'm assuming I would need to a script-block after the start-job to initiate the restore.  My task completes without errors but the restore doesn't execute so thinking my parameters aren't passing in.         Start-Job  -scriptblock {Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $arg[0] -Database $arg[1] -BackupFile $arg[2] -ReplaceDatabase $LASTEXITCODE} -ArgumentList $restorelist.SQLInstance, $restorelist.Database, $restorelist.NewBackupPath

Answer (score 0):

I used the RunspaceFactory example and modified it to use a script-block to execute Restore-SqlDatabase.   I'm sure there may be cleaner or simpler ways of doing this but so far it seems to work.